# Had Koi for five winters this year they have all slowly died in a span of a week

Tags: pond, koi

My wife was at our local Country Garden where the women said we should remove the filter for the winter. I have left the filter running the last five winters and have never had a problem. But this year, due to a recent heart attack I decided to take it out based on the recommendation. After only four days three fish died, I put the filter back in and every day several fish have died, totalling all thirteen now. I am heartbroken.

Comment: it is always sad to loose fish but to help you i will need some information,what is the readings of your latest watertest ammonia-nitrite-nitrate and PH.how large is your pond in litres and what is the temparature right now.

Comment: Size of pond? Size of fish ; were they  3" 5 yr ago and now 30" ? They don' t eat when water is as cold as 50 F , so food would foul the water.  Low temperatures and filters do not harm koi. Low oxygen ( crowding ) and bad water ( fouling, chlorination, any cleaning product) can kill koi.